# R: JBDC result query using a loop

Tags: r, loops, jdbc

I am trying to run several queries with one chunk of code to save time. Normally, I enter the variable and time, and return the results one at a time. However, there should be a way to use a loop that I iterate several variables through with one line, and collect the results in a data.frame with embedded code. However, I keept getting met with error "Error in dbSendQuery(con, sql) : Unable to retrieve JDBC result set..."

```
#enter sensor
sensor <- a
#enter start
t_start <- c("2022-07-29 04:54:00.0")
#enter end
t_end <-c("2022-08-01 23:59:59.0")
#open con
con <- openConn()

s <- tbl(con, in_schema("doc","sensors"))
consol_final <- s %>%
  filter(timeStamp >= t_start & t_end >= timeStamp,
          topic %in% sensor) %>%
  select("timeStamp", "ID", "running", "value") %>% 
  collect() %>%
  arrange(timeStamp)
closeConn
```

There must be a way to do this much faster than manually changing this using iteration. Here is my attempt that won't work no matter how much I tinker with it:

```
solution <- list()
sensor_list <- c(a,b,c,d,e,f) #note each of these is an object containing a topic URL
s <- tbl(con, in_schema("doc","sensors"))
con <- openConn()
for (i in 1:length(sensor_list)){
  consol_final <- s %>%
    filter(timeStamp >= t_start & t_end >= timeStamp,
          topic %in% sensor_list[i]) %>%
    select("timeStamp", "ID", "running", "value") %>%
    collect() %>%
    arrange(timeStamp)
  rbind(consol_final, solution)
}
```

I am very limited with my understanding of JBDC queries so it is difficult to wrap my head around the problem here. There also must be a solution to iterate through several time periods stored in a list as well. If possible, please advise on this as well. Thank you!!

Comment: Why are you constantly opening and closing your data base connection?! This adds a huge amount of overhead. What is the reason you download the table again and again inside your loop instead of doing it just once outside? (Talking about your `s` variable. Also, in your loop, where do you get the `sensors` variable you iterate over? Do you mean `sensor_list`? And why are you growing your list with rbind? That has to be the slowest/most ram-intensive way possible to save your loop results. I have more questions than characters to ask them with (in one post) but i hope i got the most pressing...

Comment: I am connecting to a private and sensitive server of information and need to close the connection frequently. You can see in my post I assigned an object to sensor, and then assign a list of objects to sensor list, and the note says that each of them contain a topic URL... I do not see how your questions pertain to the main question. I realize it may not be the fastest way to do it, but its sufficient to me and I need to understand how to do the loop. Enhancing it beyond that in terms of efficiency is just extra credit

Comment: As youhave deduced my **comment** is not an **answer** - for a reason. The way your code is written introduces (imo) so many "weak points" that I am not suprised the code breaks somewhere. My point(s) aim to show where/how to reduce the steps your code has to da to a minimum, not (just) for speed and/or memory gains but simply to eliminate errors.

Comment: I have misunderstood some of your points and made corrections to the code above. However, the loop still doesn't work. The base code in the first box of code runs fine, but the second box with the loops cannot retrieve the JDBC result set